# connecting to TFS using REST Client java

Tags: java, rest, tfs

Can I connect to the TFS using Rest Client?

If yes then , is there any standard URL that can be used to  connect to the server (my server is TFS online)

so that I can create an issue  or get an issue using HTTP POST

Comment: Have you investigated the [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22616)?

Comment: is it connecting to server using rest? i should check that

Comment: @user2334391 No, it uses SOAP.  But that's an implementation detail, it's a Java API for handling work item tracking.  If you want to speak REST, follow Santosh's guidance below.  If you want a Java API, use the SDK.

Comment: @ Edward Thomson when connecting to `https://mysite.visualstudio.com`  it is shows  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.microsoft.tfs.jni.internal.platformmisc.NativePlatformMisc.nativeGetEnvironmentVariable(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;` this is the following code i tried. `Credentials cred = new UsernamePasswordCredentials ("username", "password");
 URI serverURI = new URI("https://mysite.visualstudio.com");
 TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc = 
            new TFSTeamProjectCollection(serverURI, cred);
 WorkItemClient workItemClient = tpc.getWorkItemClient();`

Answer (score 1):

Team Foundation server has REST access. Its called **[Web Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892990%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)**. Here is an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822136%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) of usage.

**EDIT:**

Even if `Web Access` is a GUI, it also provide the access to the details via the URLs. Check the example link. Don't treat **REST as new invention**, its the way web works. Create URLs, with appropriate parameters and hit the server. There are many libraries including [apache-httpclient](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-apache-httpclient/) which facilitate this.

Comment: @user2334391, I have put additional details in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I suggets you to use `com.microsoft.tfs.core`

link : http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7a3c4332-6998-48ec-b689-e434d4218012

sample : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/05/16/announcing-a-java-sdk-for-tfs.aspx

Comment: go to the target http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7a3c4332-6998-48ec-b689-e434d4218012
 and click on download link

Comment: i was able to download. but after that we need to set the native code libraries for TFS. but i was not able to do that.[check this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a5f75f36-7d46-4bc1-aa45-5aea42b49764/tfs-sdk-native-library-error-in-a-web-service-deployed-on-axis2tomcat7ubuntu-platform?forum=tee#c8e902cb-9b8e-4b11-9c57-fee91c0fe2dc)

Comment: it's another question user2334391, i suggets you to create another question

Answer (score 0):

Set below as VM options while running your Java program to get rid of this error.

```
-Dcom.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base-directory=<path to tfs native libraries>/tfs/native
```

Note: You must have received tfs native lib as part of TFS Java SDK.